# "controlling for" a variable

Tags: controlling-for-a-variable

In my analysis section where I used a partial least squares (PLS) structural equation technique, A reviewer commented that:
"Not controlling for state or university etc, particularly in a diverse country like Nigeria, is a serious limitation in the quantitative analysis"

What did he mean, and any possible solutions, please?
Thank you

Comment: Did you read the tag description for [tag:controlling-for-a-variable]? Do you have a specific question about the topic?

Comment: @Sycorax [explain-model-adjustment-in-plain-english](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/explain-model-adjustment-in-plain-english) seems a little better in this case